# Issue with drawn object speeding up in a loop

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, graphics, draw

So I have an assignment where I have to get bugs to draw to the screen (no problem) and then shoot off from the bugbag drawn at the bottom of the screen (also no problem). However, my issue is that when the code loops, the speed picks up for some reason and everything I've tried to move around to fix the issue has proved fruitless. I either get it to slow was day (but not loop through the amount taken in) or nothing changes. Here is a code snippet from where the loop resides, I can provide more if need be, but I'm positive the problem stems from this method.

```
Point2D creatureThrow(Creature& myCreature, BugBag& theBag)
{

    //Added for creature
    Point2D creatureLocation = Point2D(CREATURE_DRAW_LEFT, 0);

    int startingBugCount = theBag.getBugCount();
    //std::vector<Bug> deadBugs(startingBugCount);

    //Create bug
    Bug* bug = new Bug();

    // Display all the bugs
    for (int bugNumber = 1; bugNumber <= startingBugCount; bugNumber++)
    {

        bug->moveTo(0, -90);

            for (int step = 0; step < BUG_STEP_SIZE; step++) // 20 is the number of steps
            {

                gdsWindow.clear();


                for (int j=0; j < bugNumber; j++) //move bugs
                {
                    //bug->draw();
                    bug->moveBy(0, 8);
                }

                myCreature.draw();
                theBag.draw();
                bug->draw();
                Sleep(FRAME_SLEEP);
            }   


    }

    return creatureLocation;
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what behaviour you're experiencing and what you're expecting. "I either get it to slow was day (but not loop through the amount taken in) or nothing changes." - what does this mean?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand, but the `moveBy` calls repeat `20 * bugNumber` times, and `bugNumber` is just your outermost loop variable.  But you only have one `Bug` object in the whole process. Don't you want something like creating your `Bug` objects inside the outer loop, and then in the innermost loop calling `moveBy` on all bugs created so far? You'd want to store them all in a vector in such a case, of course.

Comment: Essentially when the program draws the bug being "shot" out of the bugbag, it starts of at a slow speed and then each bug drawn after speeds up/starts further up the screen. Not sure why it is doing that.

Comment: Also I was testing with one bug before I moved on to adding multiple.

Comment: not sure if I get ir right but if  `bug->moveTo(0, -90);` is to restore position of bug after inner loop then 1. should not it be after it not before it, 2. may be your inner loop is moved not by 90 but +/- 1 iteration step from that so changing the 90  by +/- one step should repair the problem.

Comment: @Spektre I actually figured it out and forgot to update it here. It was the Bug->moveBy(0,8); that was the problem. This was because the loop kept adding to the process each time it incremented. Meaning that for each time through it would do it one more time than the last. It was a stupid issue, but one I ultimately figured out in the end! :D